# Spring Boot migration from 1.5 to 2.0 and quotes around parameters in JPA repository queries

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm upgrading an application from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.0 and my Spring Data JPA repositories are broken. I turned on query logging in my PostgreSQL 9.6 db to see what was different in the queries before and after the application upgrade and observed that as of 2.0, query parameters are being wrapped in double quotes which is unnecessary and breaking. Here's what I'm seeing in the query log:

**Spring Boot 1.5.22**

```
LOG:  execute <unnamed>: select siteentity0_.site_id as site_id1_14_, siteentity0_.description as descript2_14_, siteentity0_.directory as director3_14_, siteentity0_.ip_address as ip_addre4_14_, siteentity0_.name as name5_14_, siteentity0_.server as server6_14_, siteentity0_.status as status7_14_, siteentity0_.type as type8_14_ from site siteentity0_ where siteentity0_.ip_address=$1
DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '127.0.0.1'
```

**Spring Boot 2.0.9**

```
LOG:  execute <unnamed>: select siteentity0_.site_id as site_id1_14_, siteentity0_.description as descript2_14_, siteentity0_.directory as director3_14_, siteentity0_.ip_address as ip_addre4_14_, siteentity0_.name as name5_14_, siteentity0_.server as server6_14_, siteentity0_.status as status7_14_, siteentity0_.type as type8_14_ from site siteentity0_ where siteentity0_.ip_address=$1
DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '"127.0.0.1"'
```

I've checked all the release notes and migration guide and can't find anything that would explain this, nor can I find any similar reports. Any ideas?

**EDIT**:
The repository:

```
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface SiteRepository extends JpaRepository<SiteEntity, Integer> {
    SiteEntity findByName(String siteName);

    Collection<SiteEntity> findByIpAddress(String ipAddress);

    Collection<SiteEntity> findByStatus(String status);

    Collection<SiteEntity> findByType(String type);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the repository code here for this query?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not passing the value escaping the double quote? Like: `findByIpAddress("\"127.0.0.1\"")`.

Comment: I'm not escaping any quotes. Nothing has changed in the code other than the bare minimum to update the code to Spring Boot 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had an attribute converter for converting JSON to string with autoApply set to true. I changed it to false and now it works. I suppose autoApply is more permissive in 2.x.

```
@Converter(autoApply = false)
public class JpaConverterJson implements AttributeConverter<Object, String> {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace if the parameters contains double quote to empty